# POST request to GitHub API

Tags: javascript, api, github

I'm having trouble making a POST request to the GitHub API using the JavaScript fetch method:

```
fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/organization/repo/issues?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET', {
      method: 'post',
      body: {
        title: 'Title',
        body: {body: "body", title: "title"}
      }
    })
```

I am using a client ID and a client secret that I got from registering the application with the GitHub API:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: I am just getting a generic `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: @rufer7  Yes that is correct. I want to be able to submit a new issue in a repo via REST within my app, not to allow users to login. Thank you for your quick reply.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you need access token to access Github API. If you want to try manually here's my suggestion steps.
I will try to explain from the first step.

---

1. Register your app.

   On your github account, go to `settings -> OAuth Applications`

   [This is the image when you register your application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOWKa.png)

---

2. Get the Client ID and Client Secret.

   [This is the image after you receive Client ID and Client Secret](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IStKU.png)

---

3. Ask for Github Code

   Now you have `Client ID`. Go to this url.

   `https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=b420627027b59e773f4f&scope=user:email,repo`

   Please define your own `client_id` and `scope`.

---

4. Get the Github Code

   Remember the Authorization callback URL you input when register?
   After you go to the link above, you should have redirected to your callback URL with the code as the parameter.

   For example `http://localhost:8080/github/callback?code=ada5003057740988d8b1`

---

5. Ask and Get the Access Token

   Now you need to do http request post with `Client ID`, `Client Secret`, and `Code` you have got as the parameter.

   **Request**

   `POST https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token?client_id=a989cd9e8f0137ca6c29&client_secret=307d18600457b8d9eec1efeccee79e34c603c54b&code=ada5003057740988d8b1`

   **Response**

   `access_token=e72e16c7e42f292c6912e7710c838347ae178b4a&token_type=bearer`

---

6. Post Issue to Github

   Now you have `access token` you can use it to access Github API.

```js
fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/organization/repo/issues?access_token=e72e16c7e42f292c6912e7710c838347ae178b4a', {
      method: 'post',
      body: {
        title: 'Title',
        body: {body: "body", title: "title"}
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want you have to implement the web application flow described [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#web-application-flow).

This means you have to redirect the user to `https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI` so that he can login to GitHub and authorize your application. After successful login GitHub redirects you to the `redirect_uri`, which usually points to an endpoint of your application. This endpoint extracts the authorization code from the URI to request an access token from GitHub with it (See [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#2-github-redirects-back-to-your-site)). As soon as you have the access token you can consume the GitHub API by sending the OAuth token in the `Authorization` header as follows.

```
Authorization: token OAUTH-TOKEN
```